# Is there an equivalent of R's dput() for Matlab?

Tags: r, matlab, matrix

Is there an equivalent of R's dput() for Matlab?

The dput() writes an ASCII text representation of an R object to a file or connection.

Comment: Do you consider writing binary representation also?

Comment: No - just looking for a simple way to email or post structured data that has the same ease as R's dput()

Comment: @QuantGuy See my answer, below. Just let me know what other data types you need, and I'll try to add those next. Great idea, by the way!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**UPDATE 1**: Added recursion and support for cells!

**UPDATE 2**: Added support for structures!

**UPDATE 3**: Added support for logicals, integers, complex doubles. Added unit tests. Posted to FileExchange at: http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/34076

**NOTE**: Check github at https://github.com/johncolby/dput for all further updates.

---

There is no built-in equivalent, but the template to create one is simple enough, so I thought I'd start making it. Just loop over the variables and write a string equivalent depending on the type of the data.

I started a git repository for this, so feel free to fork it and help me out with different data types. I'll post it on FileExchange when the basic types are complete (double, char, struct, cell at least).

https://github.com/johncolby/dput

Starting with some example variables

```
x = 1:10;
y = 3;
z = magic(3);
mystr = ['line1'; 'line2'];
mystruct = mystruct = struct('index', num2cell(1:3), 'color', {'red', 'blue', 'green'}, 'misc', {'string' 4 num2cell(magic(3))})
mycell = {1:3, 'test'; [], 1};
```

the basic usage is:

```
>> dput(x, y, z, mystr, mystruct, mycell)

ans =

x        = reshape([1.000000 2.000000 3.000000 4.000000 5.000000 6.000000 7.000000 8.000000 9.000000 10.000000 ],[1  10])                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      ;
y        = reshape([3.000000 ],[1  1])                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         ;
z        = reshape([8.000000 3.000000 4.000000 1.000000 5.000000 9.000000 6.000000 7.000000 2.000000 ],[3  3])                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 ;
mystr    = reshape('lliinnee12',[2  5])                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        ;
mystruct = struct('index',reshape({reshape([1.000000 ],[1  1]) reshape([2.000000 ],[1  1]) reshape([3.000000 ],[1  1]) },[1  3]),'color',reshape({reshape('red',[1  3]) reshape('blue',[1  4]) reshape('green',[1  5]) },[1  3]),'misc',reshape({reshape('string',[1  6]) reshape([4.000000 ],[1  1]) reshape({reshape([8.000000 ],[1  1]) reshape([3.000000 ],[1  1]) reshape([4.000000 ],[1  1]) reshape([1.000000 ],[1  1]) reshape([5.000000 ],[1  1]) reshape([9.000000 ],[1  1]) reshape([6.000000 ],[1  1]) reshape([7.000000 ],[1  1]) reshape([2.000000 ],[1  1]) },[3  3]) },[1  3]));
mycell   = reshape({reshape([1.000000 2.000000 3.000000 ],[1  3]) reshape([ ],[0  0]) reshape('test',[1  4]) reshape([1.000000 ],[1  1]) },[2  2])                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             ;
```

Then you can just paste the text online to make a reproducible example, and others can copy/paste back into MATLAB to regenerate the variables. Just like for R!

Comment: Terrific. Big contribution via github to the general community by the way, thanks again!

Comment: I get errors when I try to get the dput-style thing: http://pastebin.com/Atz696me

Comment: John:Great answer and very helpful for those of use coming from R. I wonder if you'd consider adding support for timeseries objects? I'm new to MatLab and if I can figure it out myself I'll send it along.

Comment: I know "thanks" comments are frowned upon, but ... Wow this is an incredibly helpful tool.

Answer (score 4):

The question obviously presumes a working Matlab installation. If you want to construct examples in R using data in Matlab objects, there is obviously `readMat` in the "R.matlab" package. You could extract data from a Matlab file (or use a server connection) with R and then use `dput` or `dump`.

Within just Matlab, at least accoring to my reading of the documentation, the option I see (and it may be only applicable to Matlab matrices) is

```
filename='asc.txt'
save(filename, 'mat', '-ascii')
type asc.txt
```

There is also the option (although not really in the spirit of ASCII) of using the Common Data Format for which there are Matlab-write and R-read functions.

Comment: I believe the OP actually wants to construct MATLAB examples with the same ease he can create R examples. Is this correct?

Comment: MATLAB's `save()` does indeed have a limitation that "Each variable must be a two-dimensional double or char array". Further, these aren't paste-able, so don't really have any advantage for posting ease-of-use over just using the normal binary .mat representation.

Answer (score 0):

```
>> dput(x, y, z, mystr, mystruct, mycell)

ans =

x        = reshape([1.000000 2.000000 3.000000 4.000000 5.000000 6.000000 7.000000 8.000000 9.000000 10.000000 ],[1  10])                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      ;
y        = reshape([3.000000 ],[1  1])                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         ;
z        = reshape([8.000000 3.000000 4.000000 1.000000 5.000000 9.000000 6.000000 7.000000 2.000000 ],[3  3])                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 ;
mystr    = reshape('lliinnee12',[2  5])                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        ;
mystruct = struct('index',reshape({reshape([1.000000 ],[1  1]) reshape([2.000000 ],[1  1]) reshape([3.000000 ],[1  1]) },[1  3]),'color',reshape({reshape('red',[1  3]) reshape('blue',[1  4]) reshape('green',[1  5]) },[1  3]),'misc',reshape({reshape('string',[1  6]) reshape([4.000000 ],[1  1]) reshape({reshape([8.000000 ],[1  1]) reshape([3.000000 ],[1  1]) reshape([4.000000 ],[1  1]) reshape([1.000000 ],[1  1]) reshape([5.000000 ],[1  1]) reshape([9.000000 ],[1  1]) reshape([6.000000 ],[1  1]) reshape([7.000000 ],[1  1]) reshape([2.000000 ],[1  1]) },[3  3]) },[1  3]));
mycell   = reshape({reshape([1.000000 2.000000 3.000000 ],[1  3]) reshape([ ],[0  0]) reshape('test',[1  4]) reshape([1.000000 ],[1  1]) },[2  2])                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             ;
```

Then you can just paste the text online to make a reproducible example, and others can copy/paste back into MATLAB to regenerate the variables.