# How to find the command by which certain struct done in Matlab?

Tags: matlab

Suppose `a` is defined as the struct below.  I tried to find equivalent command to R's dput but errs [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8377575/is-there-an-equivalent-of-rs-dput-for-matlab). For example, I know that the below must be of the form `struct('const',1,'terms',{{struct(),struct()}})` but I don't know what is stored inside the structure without going to check it with commands like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15685498/beautifying-the-output-of-matlab-aka-human-readable-form-for-output), time-consuming.

**So by which command I can see the original command to generate a struct in Matlab?**

```
>> a

a =

    const: 1
    terms: {[1x1 struct]  [1x1 struct]}
```

Comment: You could go recursively through all the levels of the struct with the 'fieldname' command.

Comment: @tashuhka but I want to get the original command by which the structure was generated without me retyping things. It is unrelastic for me to do it with an extremely large structure, this command would considerable help testing. There must be some command to do this.

Comment: Type `a =` and then press up on the keypad. The console will find the last line that started with `a =`. Unless you're talking about some struct you didn't generate. In which case I don't think it's possible...

Comment: @wakjah won't work if `a`'s assignment in a script. Now the only way for me to get the assignment of `a` is to go through the code but it is slow because `a` was defined recursively. I need a command like `dput` to do this, no round-around. I need to verify the output of a script for unit-testing. For this, I need to find the right assignment succintly (without eg. recursive def).

Comment: Is it possible for you to switch from using a structure to a class? If so you could make one that mimics the struct, and each time it is modified call `stack = dbstack` to get the stack - then store the stack along with the change. The command that made the change could then be retrieved automatically later from the line numbers in the stack.

Comment: @wakjah I cannot understand, can you show some example? My peers have implementated arithmetics for multilinear functions with structs like [here](http://pastebin.com/Lr08w2E7) -- it may not be possible to change from struct to class, I need to ask. If you can show an example, what you are meaning -- it could be easier to explain this to them. It may be possible, I don't know. My peers haven't said why they started to use structs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Comment**

> *Is it possible for you to switch from using a structure to a class? If so you could make one that mimics the struct, and each time it is modified call stack = dbstack to get the stack - then store the stack along with the change. The command that made the change could then be retrieved automatically later from the line numbers in the stack.*

As a follow-up request to this in the comment, here is an example of a class that provides struct functionality and also keeps a record of its assignments:

```
classdef utstruct
    properties (SetAccess = private)
        modifications
    end

    properties (Dependent, SetAccess = private)
        myStruct
    end

    properties (Access = private)
        m_struct
    end

    methods
        function self = utstruct(varargin)
            if nargin > 0
                self.m_struct = builtin('struct', varargin{:});
            else
                self.m_struct = builtin('struct');
            end
            % Should update self.modifications here
        end

        function B = subsref(self, s)
            if any(strcmp(s(1).subs, properties(self)))
                B = builtin('subsref', self, s);
            else
                B = subsref(self.m_struct, s);
            end
        end

        function A = subsasgn(self, s, b)
            self.m_struct = subsasgn(self.m_struct, s, b);

            newMod = builtin('struct');
            newMod.type = 'subsasgn';
            newMod.modData = {s b};
            newMod.stack = dbstack;
            self.modifications = [self.modifications; newMod];

            A = self;
        end

        function disp(self)
            disp(self.m_struct);
        end

        function names = fieldnames(self, varargin)
            names = fieldnames(self.m_struct, varargin{:});
        end

        function C = cat(self, dim, varargin)
            uts = cellfun(@(x)isa(x, 'utstruct'), varargin);
            varargin{uts} = cellfun(@(x)x.m_struct, varargin(uts));
            varargin = [{self.m_struct} varargin];
            self.m_struct = cat(dim, varargin{:});

            % Should update self.modifications here

            C = self;
        end

        function C = horzcat(self, varargin)
            C = self.cat(1, varargin{:});
        end

        function C = vertcat(self, varargin)
            C = self.cat(2, varargin{:});
        end

        function value = get.myStruct(self)
            value = self.m_struct;
        end
    end
end
```

You should add some code to update the modifications array when initialisation / concatenation operations occur.

The `subsref` and `subsasgn` overrides are the key points here that make it behave like a struct (by deferring all their activity to an actual struct), but other overrides like `fieldnames` and `disp` do the same thing. In `subsasgn` a record of all the assignments to the struct is kept, along with the stack that generated the assignment.

**Note:** for this to be fully compatible with the built-in `struct` you probably should override a few more methods, but this should be enough to get you started. See [Subclassing MATLAB Built-In Types](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/matlab_oop/subclassing-matlab-built-in-classes.html).

**Edit:** I made the example a bit more robust. It's now a value class - as it should be - and works with concatenation.

**Edit:** You can avoid using a find-and-replace to refactor existing `struct(...)` calls by redefining the function `struct`:

```
function s = struct(varargin)
% STRUCT    Overrides default struct function to provide unit-testable structs
%
%   Set global variable unitTestStructEnabled to true to enable this
%   function.
%
global unitTestStructEnabled;

if isempty(unitTestStructEnabled)
    unitTestStructEnabled = false;
end

if unitTestStructEnabled
    s = utstruct(varargin{:});
else
    s = builtin('struct', varargin{:});
end
```

You probably don't want that hanging around on your path the whole time, as you will get a warning when you first create a struct (you could turn it off, but that might hide other problems), so you should probably put it in a folder that's not normally in the path, and temporarily add it to the path for unit testing (`addpath` / `rmpath`).

Answer (score 1):

Here's the skeleton of a `dumpvar` function, i.e. something along the idea of [tashuhka](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2039736/tashuhka)

```
function str = dumpvar(a)
        switch class(a)
        case 'double'
                if isempty(a)
                        str = '[]';  % bug when "a" is multidimensional and empty

                elseif isscalar(a)
                        str = num2str(a);

                elseif isrow(a)
                        str = strcat('[', dumpvar(a(1)));
                        for k = 2:size(a,2)
                                str = strcat(str,',',dumpvar(a(k)));
                        end;
                        str = strcat(str, ']');

                elseif numel(size(a)) == 2
                        str = strcat('[', dumpvar(a(1,:)));
                        for k = 2:size(a,1)
                                str = strcat(str,';',dumpvar(a(k,:)));
                        end;
                        str = strcat(str, ']');

                else
                        do_what_i_mean();
                end;

        case 'struct'
                fn = fieldnames(a);
                if isempty(fn)
                        str = 'struct()';

                elseif isscalar(a)
                        str = strcat('struct(''', fn{1},''',', dumpvar(a.(fn{1})));
                        for k=2:numel(fn)
                                str = strcat(str,',''',fn{k},''',', dumpvar(a.(fn{k})));
                        end;
                        str = strcat(str, ')');

                else
                        do_what_i_mean();
                end;

        otherwise
                do_what_i_mean();
        end;

        function do_what_i_mean()
                throwAsCaller(MException(...
                        'beingLazy:onSaturday:Fault', ...
                        'Storage of class "%s" and arity %d is not implemented yet. Would you?', ...
                        class(a), numel(size(a))...
                ));
        end;
end
```

Save it in a `dumpvar.m` file somewhere in Matlab's path, then test it with this code snippet:

```
a = struct(...
    'field1', 1,...
    'field2', [],...
    'field10', struct(...
        'field3', [1 2;2 3;3 4],...
        'field4', struct()...
     )...
);
disp(dumpvar(a));
eval(sprintf('b=%s;', dumpvar(a)));
```

Please note that this function is still in a toy stage: it's anywhere near exhaustive (lacks treatment of struct arrays, cells, char, logical and other fundamental types, not to mention user-defined classes --- hehe, those would be a pickle) and it is meant to be completed by you with whatever functionality you need.

Comment: The fact that Matlab does not have anything like this or like R's `dput` by default fires bells that we are reinventing the wheel. If I started from scratch, would the easiest method be to avoid this to use classes and somehow there store the assignments?

Comment: @hhh This is my opinion, not a fact: the equivalent of `dput` in Matlab would be `save`, with the difference that 1) the output is machine-readable, not human readable; 2) the output goes to a file, not to screen.

Might be that the Matlab designers thought that the IDE is enough for those who want to eye-ball deeply nested data, while a binary file is more fit to storing and retrieving that data. `dput` may be used for both purposes. There are some console functions to inspect data (e.g. `disp`, `display`) but it's not what you want.

Comment: @hhh (continued) When I proposed this "data deparser," I did it sincerely: faced with your task it is how I'd proceed. My sin is having little patience with other people's code, so often I start reinventing the wheel because of that. But apparently there's no wheel in the first place, or is buried too deep...

Comment: I know but I would like to know the "better way" also. I cannot fully understand the difference between the answers here. Is the wakjah's answer meant for better starting from scratch solution while your solution more for parsing the already-poor solution?

Comment: @hhh Well it depends really on the details of your task. If you want to compare only the organization of data, regardless what actual values are stored, I think Oleg Komarov's idea is a good solution (because you can always diff -- like in Unix `diff` -- the results from the two objects). If you want to account values also you need something that represents the actual values too (this `dumpvar` should do that once complete, with the advantage that you can just `eval` it back into existence). If you need, besides the state, variable's whole history, then wakjah's `utstruct` might be handy.

Answer (score 1):

Although it does not answer completely your question, [vsize()](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/matlabcentral/fileexchange/12278-vsize-a-pedestrian-variable-decoder) by Urs can help you:

```
% Create some complicated variable
v(1).a{1}=sparse(magic(3)+2i*magic(3));
v(2).a{2}={struct('FA',{'a','bb'},'FB',{magic(5),{}})};
v(2).b{2}=@(x) sind(x);

% Dissect        
P = vsize(v);

% -------------------------
%       1998       1998 B *   v = 2:1x2:struct.(2)
% CELL -----        360 B     v[].a = 2:1x1:cell
%       1750        248 B -   v[].a{} = 2:3x3:double.sparse.complex
% CELL -----       1014 B     v[].a = 2:1x2:cell
%       1750          0 B -   v[].a{} = 2:0x0:double
% CELL -----        894 B     v[].a{} = 2:1x1:cell
% STRUCT ---        782 B     v[].a{}{} = 2:1x2:struct.(2)
%       1748          2 B -   v[].a{}{}[].FA = 2:1x1:char
%       1744          4 B -   v[].a{}{}[].FA = 2:1x2:char
%       1544        200 B -   v[].a{}{}[].FB = 2:5x5:double
% CELL -----          0 B     v[].a{}{}[].FB = 2:0x0:cell
%       1544          0 B -   v[].b = 2:0x0:double
% CELL -----        152 B     v[].b = 2:1x2:cell
%       1544          0 B -   v[].b{} = 2:0x0:double
%       1512         32 B -   v[].b{} = 2:1x1:function_handle
```