# How to redirect stdout to stdin in Matlab? Aka how to manage file-descriptors?

Tags: matlab, file-descriptor

My peers have created an extremely-hard-to-test novel [structure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15985647/how-to-find-the-command-by-which-certain-struct-done-in-matlab) where they use stdout for outputting results. Now I cannot change their code and I need to use their functions. Suppose a function `mlfpprint` that uses stdout for displaying results -- now I need to check whether its results are correct so I need to get the stdout to a variable for comparison with the correct result. So

**How can I manage file-descriptors in Matlab? For example, how can I get stdout to stdin?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One idea would be to use [`diary`](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/matlab/ref/diary.html) to save the output of your function call/script to a file. Then parse the file. Also as Oleg recommended, you can use [evalc](http://www.mathworks.se/help/matlab/ref/evalc.html) like `evalc('functionName')`.

Comment: @hhh If you want to use `evalc` to call your function, maybe you should do `evalc('arbitraryAmountOfPrints(someArgList)')`, because `evalc` expects the expression that needs to be evaluated as a string.

Comment: @hhh I get that error if I call `[a,b] = evalc('disp()')`. Now, even If I have a function which loops the `disp()`, I can still capture all prints with `a = evalc(myLoopDisp)`.

Comment: You need to pass a string to `evalc()`, so it would be evalc('hello').
It's easy to forget to encapsulate into `''` and as a matter of fact I forgot them in my previous comment....

Comment: @hhh Sorry for insisting ;-), but you should call your function like this: http://pastebin.com/cFPVK4N3

Comment: Moved the follow-up question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15991945/sanitize-string-for-comparison-in-matlab), I already know a hack to do this but there may be better ways...big thanks for your ideas!