# Sanitize string for comparison in Matlab

Tags: string, matlab, consistency, sanitization

This is a follow-up question from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15990891/how-to-redirect-stdout-to-stdin-in-matlab-aka-how-to-manage-file-descriptors) that considered `evalc`, instead of figgling with file-descriptors manually. You can see below an example about poor sanitization. I want to remove things such as trailing characters, all whitespaces, all newlines etc -- that usually cause unexpected things -- **is there a ready sanitization command to do this?**

```
EDU>> a

a =

1 +1*{x} -1*{y}*{z}


EDU>> b

b =

1 +1*{x} -1*{y}*{z}

EDU>> isequal(a,b)

ans =

     0
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't know whether there exist any ready robust implementation but this works pretty well

```
xx=@(x)regexprep(x,'\s',''); isequal(xx(a),xx(b))
```

where I use anonymous function and remove some oddities such as trailing whitespaces/newlines often hard to see on the window.

Also, the commands such as `strtrim()` and `deblank()` can be useful to you in removing trailing characters.

Comment: [`deblank`](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/matlab/ref/deblank.html) might work too.

Comment: @CST-Link yes that is good point, actually it was the command that I tested also but I think strtrim does it and more so deblank not needed in this case. And actually the `regexprep` is very powerful so should be enough here but the other commands may be useful to other people reading this in the future. Thanks for the point!

Comment: @hhh: how about removing all whitespace characters: `sanitize = @(str) regexprep(str,'\s+','')`?

Comment: @Amro this is what I do there with ` |\n`, sure `\s|\n` is better (fixed) but why would you like to have a plus there? I see no point for it.

Comment: @hhh: its a regular expression: `\s` is equivalent to `[ \f\n\r\t\v]` (any of: space, tab, carriage return, line feed, form feed). `+` means "one or more occurrences"

Comment: @hhh: I guess the `+` doesnt matter here.. either way you don't need the redundant `\n` or `strtrim` now

Comment: @Amro sure. Now it should be fine.